# Import QML Components from Custom QML Library

Tags: qt, qml, pyside

I have created a library to store custom QML components that I am making for an application. I am using Pyside6 with python. This is what the basic directory looks like:

```
library
|    |__CustomComponents
|       |__Components1  
|          |__CustomComponent1.qml
|
|__test
   |__MainComponent
      |__main.py
      |__Main.qml
```

library and test are on the same level. I want to be able to access the CustomComponent1.qml file for use in the Main.qml, but how would I go about writing an import statement for that in Python? Also, to be able to import Components1 as a module, is the qmldir file all I need to have there? It would be neat if there is a command I can use to generate the files I need to make a module.

Edit: Possible to use QQuickView and QQmlApplicationEngine together?

```
view = QQuickView()
view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView);

newWidget = newWidget()
view.rootContext().setContextProperty("headerWidget", headerWidget)

qml_file = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / 'Main.qml')
view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_file))
if view.status() == QQuickView.Error:
    sys.exit(-1)
view.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use qmldir to indicate that there is a module in that folder and for it to be used it must be in the list of imports of the engine and for this you must use the [`addImportPath`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#addImportPath) method.

```
├── library
│   └── CustomComponents
│       └── Components1
│           ├── CustomComponent1.qml
│           └── qmldir
└── test
    └── MainComponent
        ├── main.py
        └── main.qml
```

CustomComponent1.qml

```
import QtQuick

Rectangle{
    id: root
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "salmon"
}
```

qmldir

```cpp
module Components1
CustomComponent1 CustomComponent1.qml
```

**main.py**

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

LIBRARY_DIR = CURRENT_DIRECTORY.parents[1] / "library" / "CustomComponents"


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.addImportPath(os.fspath(LIBRARY_DIR))
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml"))

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(
        handle_object_created, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection
    )

    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

import Components1

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    CustomComponent1{

    }
}
```

### QQuickView

In the case of QQuickView, it has an engine so you must use that one, so the changes are:

**main.py**

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQuick import QQuickView

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

LIBRARY_DIR = CURRENT_DIRECTORY.parents[1] / "library" / "CustomComponents"


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QQuickView()
    view.engine().addImportPath(os.fspath(LIBRARY_DIR))
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml"))

    def handle_status_changed(status):
        if status == QQuickView.Error:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    view.statusChanged.connect(
        handle_status_changed, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection
    )

    view.setSource(url)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick

import Components1

Rectangle {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    CustomComponent1{

    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you are using a `QQmlApplicationEngine`, but I am using a `QQuickView` because there are a couple global objects that I had to set with `QQuickView`'s `setContextProperty()` method. I added a snippet of how my `QQuickView` is being used into my question. Can they be combined somehow, or do I have to use `QQuickView` or `QQmlApplicationEngine`?

Comment: @SCP3008 Sir at the time of publishing my answer, your post did not indicate anything about QQuickView so my answer could validly cover several elements (QQmlApplicationEngine, QQuickView, QQuickWidget, etc) or I was only concentrating on the one that seemed best to me (a coin to the air) In this case, opt for the latter. Please to avoid confusion in subsequent posts please be precise, it is annoying for the OP to add code after initially not posting anything, don't you think?

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble, I didn't know that it mattered whether I used QQmlApplicationEngine, QQuickView, or etc because I thought importing from another directory was just about writing the import statements correctly/adding in qmldir. I'm deeply grateful and thankful for the time and effort you spend helping me with this though.